# Can you use python to type text and press enter in command prompt?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, enter, pycassa

I made a little python function, which I would then like to use in a Linux command prompt. However, in order for it to run correctly in the command prompt, I need to first type "pycassaShell" into the command prompt so that pycassaShell is running before I input any further commands. Thus, is there any way to do this in my python program itself?

For example, I would like the python code to do the following:

- Open command prompt
- Enter "pycassaShell"
- Press enter key
- Run the function I created in the python program.

Alternatively, is it possible to simply access a function written in a python file directly in pycassaShell?

I apologize if this is a bad question, but I am new to using command prompt in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*pycassa* is a *Python* module with a full-fledged *API*. Instead of trying to operate inside of its shell from within *Python*, you should `import` the module and use it directly.

Documentation about the *API* can be found here:

http://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/api/index.html

In contrast, *pycassaShell* is the interactive shell wrapper around *pycassa* meant for manual exploration (as opposed to programmatic execution).

http://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/assorted/pycassa_shell.html

So, I would recommend that you adapt your function to use the `import`ed `pycassa` module directly as opposed to the *pycassaShell* shell. Then you can use that new function freely within your *Python* script.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Like you said, I ended up not needing to do any of that, and just ran the function directly from the program. Thanks again.